# Advantages of a Hitachi HD6309 versus a plain Motorola MC6809

Tags: 6809

Hitachi was a second source for the [Motorola 6809](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_6809) Micro Processor. The 6309 had many secret features. What advantages does the HD6309 have over the MC6809?

Comment: If someone asks something about an Amiga chip, is that too localized? I don't know why asking the difference between two manufactures of an old chip would be considered off topic for retrocomputing..

Comment: Yeah, what he said. Everyone should totally up vote this Q&A.

Comment: The 6309 is used as a CPU upgrade for the CoCo 3 and OS-9 was modified to support the additional features.

Comment: @BrianBlake That looks like an "answer". Why post it as a "Comment"?

Comment: Man, me and this system are fighting, lol, My answer yesterday got deleted due to the link. I figured a link was better to avoid reinventing the wheel, but, whatever, it's not my site. Gimme a minute and I'll try to post it as an answer...

Comment: @BrianBlake I really liked your answer. I up voted it. You gave a nice summary, then a link to more information. I think the Mods should encourage that kind of answer.

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration to upgrade my CoCo 3. OS-9 is already amazing, for an 8-bit OS, just on the 6809.

Answer (score 24):

The basic improvements over the 6809: - 2 more 8bit accumulators; additional 8 & 16 bit registers - native and 6809 emulation modes - fewer execution cycles in native mode - improved instruction set - error trapping (illegal instruction & divide by zero) - roughly 10% speed increase in emulation mode/40% in native mode (both application dependant) - variants include 3Mhz parts.

Much more detailed information can be found in a memo written by Hirotsugu Kakugawa [link](http://fms.komkon.org/comp/CPUs/6309.txt).

Below are excepts from the link (this is NOT my writing, I'm reposting existing information):

> The CPU 6309 by HITACHI has secret features which is not written in
>   its manual.  The purpose of this memo is to introduce them.   The
>   features was originally reported in a magazine,  Oh!FM (1988 Apr.),
>   which was written in Japanese.  I did not tried all of the features
>   reported in the article, but I report the features as far as I know.
>
> HITACHI says in the manual of 6309 that 6309 is compatible with 6809,
>   but some OS-9 hackers found that it has secret features.
>
> It has following features:
>    1. More registers (additional two 8 bit accumulators, 8 bit
>        register, and a 16 bit register), 
>    2. Two modes (6809 emulation mode and native mode),
>    3. Reduced execution cycles in native mode,
>    4. More instructions (16 bit x 16 bit multiplication, 32 bit / 16 bit
>       division, inter-registers operation, block transfer, bit
>       manipulating operation which is compatible with 6801 has, etc)
>    5. Error trap by illegal instruction, zero division.
>
> The 6309 has some additional registers that 6809 does not.
>
> 1. The E register, the F register 
>       These are 8 bit accumulators.  Like the D register is a pair of 
>       the A register and the B register, these two registers can be
>       used as a 16 bit accumulator. The pair of the E and the F
>       registers is called the W register.
>       In addition to that, pair of two 16 bit registers, the D register
>       and the W register, can be used as a 32 bit accumulator called the
>       Q register.
> 2. The V register
>       This a 16 bit register can be used only by TFR, inter-register
>       operation, etc.  But even if the chip is reseted, contents of
>       this register does not change.  Some people  may use this
>       register to keep constant value (V for value).
> 3. The MD register
>       This is a 8 bit register to keep the mode and status of the chip.
>       The meaning of each bit is as follow.
>
>    Read value
>          bit 7  ---  1 is set if zero division happen.
>          bit 6  ---  1 is set if illegal instruction is fetched.
>
>    Write value 
>          bit 1  ---  The mode for FIRQ interrupt.
>                      0 -> the the action for FIRQ is the same as that
>                           of 6809.
>                      1 -> the the action for FIRQ is the same as IRQ.
>          bit 0  ---  The execution mode of 6309.
>                      0 -> the emulation mode.
>                      1 -> the native mode.
>
>    (When the chip is reseted, all bits are 0.)
>
> The 6309 has two modes, emulation mode and native mode, as described
>   in the previous section.  When the chip is reseted, the initial mode
>   of 6309 is the emulation mode.
>
> When the 6309 is in the emulation mode, the chip emulates the action
>   of 6809.  But we can use extended registers and extended operations in
>   this mode.  The 6309 executes instructions in the same cycles as 6809
>   does.     When the 6309 is in the native mode, it executes
>   instructions in less cycles. And when the chip is interrupted (IRQ,
>   for example),  it pushes extended registers (PC, U, Y, X, DP, W, D,
>   CC, in this order).  If you want to use the 6309, you must rewrite
>   interrupt handling routine (for example, the entry of system call of
>   OS9).
>
> NEW INSTRUCTIONS
>
> The Register Addressing Mode
>
> To specify registers in TFR and EXG, the 6809 uses bit pattern of 4
>   bits.  New registers of the 6309 are specified by bit patterns in TFR
>   and EXG operations. In addition to that, the bit pattern is also used
>   in instructions of inter-register operations.  We call this bit
>   pattern used to specify register "register addressing mode".
>
> Bit patterns for new registres are as follows:
>
> ```
> W  ->  0110,
> V  ->  0111,
> E  ->  1110,
> F  ->  1111.
> ```
>
> NOTE: even if the 6309 is in a emulation mode, the action for TFR of
>   6309  is different from that of the 6809 if new register is specified
>   in operand.  Some hackers found this fact and they guessed that the
>   6309 has secret registers. At last, they found many features.
>
> Inter-Register Operations Operations of 6809 are operations between
>   register and immediate value or between register and memory. 
>   Therefore, we had to store value of  register on memory if opetation
>   between two registers is necessary.   But the 6309 has inter-register
>   operation. Following operations are  provided:
>       ADDR r0,r1  (ADD of two registers),
>       ADCR r0,r1  (ADC of two registers),
>       SUBR r0,r1  (SUB of two registers),
>       SBCR r0,r1  (SBC of two registers),
>       ANDR r0,r1  (AND of two registers),
>       ORR  r0,r1  (OR of two registers),
>       EORR r0,r1  (EOR of two registers),
>       CMPR r0,r1  (CMP of two registers). The register addressing mode is used to specify two registers. (I do not remember exactrlly but the
>   result is stored in r0, the register of the first operand. Please try
>   and find the behavior of these instructions.)
>
> Block Transfer Block transfer instructions are provided such as Z80
>   has. The TFM instruction requires source address and destination
>   address  and block size as its argument.  One or two 16 bit registers
>   (X/Y/U/S) are used to specify source and destination addresses. Block
>   size to be  transfered is specified by the W register.  Four style is
>   provided:
>       TFR r0+,r1+  (transfered in address is increasing order),
>       TFR r0-,r1-  (transfered in address is decreasing order),
>       TFR r0+,r1   (poured into the same address, I/O port for instance),
>       TFR r0,r1+   (read from the same address, I/O port for instance). I tried this instructions but I do not remember exactly. Operand
>   registers are pointers of source/destination addresses (,maybe).
>   Please try and find the behavior of these instructions.
>
> Multiplication And Division The 6309 has MULD instruction which
>   performs a 16bit x 16bit multipli- cation. We can use various
>   addressing modes (immediate, direct, indexed, extend)  The result is
>   stored in the Q register.    Division instructions are also provided. 
>   The 6309 has two division instructions: 16bit / 8bit, 32bit / 16bit
>   divisions.  Various addressing modes (immediate, direct, indexed,
>   extend) can be  used.   (Note:I forget where its result is stored.  I
>   tried these instructions.  I remember that modulo is also computed.
>   The quotient and the modulo  are stored D and W resp., maybe. I'm not
>   sure, sorry.)
>
> Bit Manipulation / Bit Transfer The 6309 provides AIM, OIM, EIM, TIM
>   instructions which are compatible  with instructions of the Hitachi
>   6301 CPU.  Read the manual of the 6301 to understand thses
>   instructions.
>
> Instructions called BAND, BOR, BEOR, BIAND, BIOR, BIEOR, LDBT, STBT
>   are provided.  Behavior of thses instructions is that a logical
>   operation is performed for n-th bit of a data in a memory (only direct
>   mode is allowed) and m-th bit of a register, then the result is stored
>   in the register. The format of the object is :    $11, x, (post byte),
>   (operand). The say that the post byte takes strange format.  I do not
>   understand these instructions. Sorry, please try.
>
> To change modes ofthe 6309, we have to set the 0th bit of the MD
>   register.  To do this, the LDMD instruction is provided:
>       LDMD #n     (where #n is a immediate n bit data) When trap is caused, it is necessary to examine the reason of the  trap. The BITMD
>   instruction can be used for this purpose:
>       BITMD #n    (where #n is a immediate n bit data) The contents of the MD register and #n is ANDed, and changes the CC  register (,maybe,
>   I do not remember exactly). Once this instruction is executed, the 6th
>   and the 7th bit of the  MD register is CLEARED.  Therefore, we can't
>   examine the MD register.
>
> Pushing and poping the W registers on/from stack:
>       PSHSW     (Push the W register on the system stack),
>       PULSW     (Pop the W register from the system stack),
>       PSHUW     (Push the W register on the user stack),
>       PULUW     (Pop the W register from the user stack).

Answer (score 9):

[This PDF](http://www.coco3.com/community/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/6x09_Instruction_Sets.pdf) (link stale; here's [an archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200818113646if_/http://www.coco3.com/community/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/6x09_Instruction_Sets.pdf)) by Darren Atkinson gives you everything you want to know about programming differences between the two.

It begins with a very thorough Leventhal-style instruction set reference, with everything 6309-specific clearly marked, then an in-depth article about the differences, then an opcode map, then a chart of undefined opcode behavior.

Comment: Could you add a summary of the PDF to your post?  Links have a habit of going bad, making link-only answers useless.

Comment: Link-only answers aren't good for this site. Like Brian Blake's original answer, I'm going to have to delete this if information from the PDF isn't added to the answer.

Comment: As was predicted by Mark. The link is now stale.

Answer (score 8):

1. Pin and software compatible.
2. Two extra 8-bit accumulators.
3. Instruction fetch pipeline.
4. Division instruction.
5. Lower power consumption.

Comment: Source of information would be nice on this answer